# Multiple proguard configuration files for Android library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I would like to use multiple proguard configuration files in  `consumerProguardFiles`.

But when I call it like that:

`consumerProguardFiles 'proguard/proguard_library.pro','proguard/proguard_retrolambda.pro'`

then the second one is ignored.

Does anyone knows is there a possiblity to specify multiple files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but have you ever tried to use multiple lines like :

```
consumerProguardFiles 'proguard/proguard_library.pro'
consumerProguardFiles 'proguard/proguard_retrolambda.pro'
```